# Script does not work placed in body tags

Tags: javascript, html

The images named One.jpg to Ten.jpg are in a folder 'myFolder', which is at my desktop. Below is a code to rotate three images at a time from the total ten in myFolder and the html file is also in the same folder. How to write the src so that this code may work. Alert message gives the name of these 10 images, but further it does not work. Script does not work  placed in body tags. What is wrong which is to be corrected for expedted results.

```
<html>
<body>

<img  id = "im1"><img id = "im2"><img id = "im3">

<script type = "text/javascript">

var imgArray = ['One.jpg','Two.jpg','Three.jpg','Four.jpg','Five.jpg', 'Six.jpg', 'Seven.jpg', 'Eight.jpg', 'Nine.jpg', 'Ten.jpg'];

function randOrd(){return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5)}
imgArray.sort(randOrd);
alert (imgArray);  // FOR TESTING
var len = imgArray.length;
var count = 0;

rotate1();
rotate2();
rotate3();

function rotate1() {
document.getElementById("im1").src= imgArray[count];
count++;
if (count>=len) {count = 0}
var tim1 = window.setTimeout("rotate1()", 3000);  // 3 seconds
}


function rotate2() {
document.getElementById("im2").src = imgArray[count];
count++;
if (count>=len) {count = 0}
var tim2 = window.setTimeout("rotate2()", 5000);  // 5 seconds
}


function rotate3() {
document.getElementById("im3").src = imgArray[count];
count++;
if (count>=len) {count = 0}
var tim3 = window.setTimeout("rotate3()", 7000);  // 7 seconds
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the full code?

Comment: No body element ? No script element closing ? This looks like a mess.

Comment: Hi Dystroy, thanks for pointing my mistake, actually this has been due to improper copy and paste into the box. I am going to correct it.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon here: `if (count>=len) {count = 0}`. Updated my answer below.

Comment: This runs fine for me in Chrome. What is the issue you are seeing? There's not much you say about it other than "it does not work."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A best-practice says that the script should be taken out in a separate file and then included at the **end** of the body like this:

```
<script src="scripts/YourScript.js"></script>
```

where `src` points to the file.

This is good because:

- the browser renders the page as it parses it from top to bottom. This means that when it reaches the `script` part at the end of the `body` tag, your *HTML* should be loaded, so the elements used by your scripts will most likely be present.
- you can display something to the user until the slowest part (the scripts) load.
- you could server the scripts from a *CDN* so the request-response delay would be minimum.

The only exception to this rule I know of is `modernizr` or similar browser and feature detection libraries.

#### Update

You are missing a semicolon here:

`if (count>=len) {count = 0}`

it should be like:

`if (count>=len) {count = 0; }`

Also, when you pass the function to the `setTimeout` you can do it like:

`window.setTimeout(rotate3, 7000);`

Comment: Hi Andrei, I have done the corrections suggested by you, but still it did not work.

Comment: Would you check this portion of code 'function randOrd(){return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5)}'

Comment: That piece of code returns +0.5 and -0.5 so the sort should go well. What exactly do you mean by `does not work` ? Do you get any errors in console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) or nothing happens ? What would you expect to happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd load your script from an external file and there'd be no JavaScript at all in your HTML file.  Then you'd serve your documents with CSP headers.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the "best" practice thing, your problem is that you have no closing `</script>` tag.

Comment: He said he has one and that it was only a matter of copy-pasting.